# passing variable to a batch file

Tags: batch-file

i am calling a batch file for xcopy. i have the path of the file to b copied in variable a. my code is:

```
dim shell,z  
z="for.bat " & a & " " & b & " " & c  
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")  

shell.Run z, 1, true
```

where for.bat is:

```
for %%f in (%1,%2,%3) do xcopy %%f D:\shipment\ /e
```

when 'a' has small path like `D:\flexcube`, it works. but if i put some big path, say:
`D:\flexcube1\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder`
it does not work. is their some length restriction on %1 type variables or is this some other problem? any help is really appreciated.

Comment: yeah the space was the problem . thanx a lot. but still if i use this path :"\\iflblw-bpd-12\Vercon_IP-BPD-01\SOFT\FLEXCUBE_Sites\BCHICL(BDC)\FC_UBS_V.UL.6.6.0.0.BCHICL.7.0" it does not work. any guesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing the directory name in quotes like this:

```
"D:\flexcube1\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder"
```

Comment: yeah the space was the problem . thanx a lot. but still if i use this path :"\\iflblw-bpd-12\Vercon_IP-BPD-01\SOFT\FLEXCUBE_Sites\BCHICL(BDC)\FC_UBS_V.UL.6.6.0.0.BCHICL.7.0" it does not work. any guesses?

Comment: i tried it again. now its working. may b i had done some typing error. thanx for all the help

Answer (score 4):

`space` is the problem. `D:\flexcube1\New Folder\New Folder\` has space between New and Folder. You need to provide `""` around the path.

Answer (score 0):

In your path (
`D:\flexcube1\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder`) There are spaces between the word `New` and the word `Folder`. What I suggest you should do, is put quotes around it which will make it look like this:

```
"D:\flexcube1\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder\New Folder"
```